# std::once_flag equivalent of BOOST_ONCE_INIT

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working with some code I borrowed from [here](http://www.boostcookbook.com/Recipe:/1235044) which uses boost::call_once to make a singleton class, and would like to convert everything to use C++0x's std::call_once to remove the dependency on Boost. Does anyone know what the Std equivalent of BOOST_ONCE_INIT is?

Comment: How exactly is the code 'borrowed'?  are you going to give it back when you're done with it?

Comment: Beware of this sample code - it isn't safe in static usage. You'll end up with a static race condition between compilation units that reference the singleton. My experiments with this code resulted in my singleton type being initialized, and then the scoped_ptr being overwritten by null, whilst the once condition having already been satisfied.

Comment: I had this same problem - things seem to be better if I use a raw pointer rather than the scoped one.

Comment: Easier if you flat out don't use a singleton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::once_flag` has a `constexpr` constructor, so instances with static storage duration are always statically initialized.

Incidentally, the point about `scoped_ptr` is important --- the constructor of the `scoped_ptr` instance is NOT static initialization, so will race with any uses of the singleton before it has been initialized, and possibly overwrite the pointer.